# implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2' into dependencies in Android studio (java ) ":show me error:"

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an error when adding the following into dependencies (Module : app)

`implementation'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'`

The error:

```
Could not find com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2.
Required by:
   project :app
```

Comment: That library has not been updated in a few years. You could try adding `jcenter()` to your list of artifact repositories. Otherwise, you may need to [build it from source](https://github.com/ashik94vc/ElegantNumberButton).

Comment: how can i build it from source